# scroll through href li using jquery.serial scroll

Tags: jquery, serialscroll

How would I get to the next item on the list;

```
<ul>
     <li><a href="#one">ONE</a></li>
     <li><a href="#two">TWO</a></li>
     <li><a href="#three">THREE</a></li>
     <li><a href="#four">FOUR</a></li>
     <li><a href="#five">FIVE</a></li>
  </ul>
```

using jquery serial scroll, http://flesler.blogspot.com/2008/02/jqueryserialscroll.html